# Como se puede borrar el valor

Tags: php, session

Estoy enviando un valor  una vez que se ha guardado un archivo utilizando `move_uploaded_file` , tomo el valor del nombre del archivo guardado y lo envió utilizando estas lineas.

```html
$filename = basename($filepath);
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['valor']=$filename;
```

y lo recibo en un archivo php que contiene este codigo

```html
<?php
session_start();
$filename=$_SESSION['valor'];
$directorio_escaneado = scandir('archivos/tmp');
$archivos = array();
foreach ($directorio_escaneado as $item) {
    if ($item == $filename) {
        $archivos[] = $item;
    }
}
echo json_encode($archivos);

?>
```

Con esto ya logre que se muestre el nombre del archivo guardado en el HTML, ahora el detalle es que siempre permanece ahí, como se puede hacer para eliminar ese valor una vez que se refresque la pantalla.

Saludos

Comment: Después de mostrarlo, simplemente elimina la variable de sesión: `unset($_SESSION['valor']);`

Comment: Puedes utilizar `unset()` para destruir la variable: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!   ya me funciono, tenia un error de dedo.  :)